# Left outer join with MongoDB

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, sqlite, left-join

I have migrated my sqlite3 database to MongoDB with `sqlitemongo`, but I'm now having a hard time converting SQL queries to work with MongoDB. I have two collections, which are in the following format:

**word2vec**

```
[
  {
    "_id":{"$numberInt":"1"},
    "word":"olla",
    "vec":<VEC_DATA>
  },
  {
    "_id":{"$numberInt":"2"},
    "word":"että",
    "vec":<VEC_DATA>
   }
]
```

**nearby**

```
[
  {
    "_id":{"$numberInt":"1"},
    "word":"arvostus",
    "neighbor":"nostattaa",
    "similarity":{"$numberDouble":"0.3088807761669159"},
    "percentile":{"$numberInt":"29"}
  },
  {
    "_id":{"$numberInt":"2"},
    "word":"arvostus",
    "neighbor":"että",
    "similarity":{"$numberDouble":"0.3020103059369159"},
    "percentile":{"$numberInt":"30"}
  }
]
```

The first query I'm struggling with looks like this:

```
SELECT vec, percentile
FROM word2vec LEFT OUTER JOIN nearby
ON nearby.word = <var1> and nearby.neighbor = <var2>
WHERE word2vec.word = <var2>
```

, where `<var1>` and `<var2>` are strings that have different values on different queries. They are given as arguments to the function that runs the query. I need the DB to return the `vec` value, regardless of whether a matching `percentile` is found. It is used whenever found. I found some information on how left joins can be done in Mongo but none of the examples weren't even close to what I was looking.

Does someone know how to make such query in Mongo? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v8hyxFf2u1n)?

Comment: No, that didn't seem to do the trick and it also seemed to run very slowly on my db. I ended up doing two separate queries which was actually better for my purposes as in some cases the second one was unnecessary.